# How can I pass UPPER(c.Name) as parameter in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`newuser`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spSelectAllCustomers`(
IN customRole VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
IF customRole IS NULL THEN
SELECT * FROM  db.Customers AS c;
ELSE
SELECT customRole FROM db.Customers AS c; 
END IF;
END

call db.spSelectAllCustomers('UPPER(c.CustomerName)');
```

SELECT UPPER(c.Name) FROM Customers AS c; i want to run this query but i want to pass UPPER(c.Name) as a parameter like SELECT customRole FROM Customers AS c;

I'm trying to send UPPER(c.Name) as argument but compiler is treating it as varchar and returning 'UPPER(c.Name)' for every row of the column 'Name'

Comment: You want to provide not a value but a code part as a parameter. You need in dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: SELECT UPPER(c.Name) FROM Customers AS c; i want to run this query but i want to pass UPPER(c.Name) as a parameter like SELECT customRole FROM Customers AS c;

Answer (score -2):

we cannot pass like below

```
EXECUTE spSelectAllCustomers, customRole=UPPER(c.Name)
```

It should be some string input like this

```
EXECUTE spSelectAllCustomers 'your value'
```

Comment: Double quotes are generally not acceptable as a string delimiter. Here you would need to assign the result of UPPER to a variable - so you approach is both logically incorrect and confusing to the inexperienced.